# deploy maven war file to tomcat from IntelliJ

Tags: java, maven-2, intellij-idea

I have a maven war project. How can I do do the following from within IntelliJ IDEA:

- create .war file
- deploy it to a local Tomcat
- start Tomcat in debug mode

Comment: must you use Tomcat? I have a trick that I use for my development, actually deploying code to jetty server once I change the code(do this with maven).

Answer (score 1):

You need to configure `maven-war-plugin` to build your war.  `tomcat<x>-maven-plugin` will allow you to deploy it to a tomcat instance and may in fact do the war generation too - I use JBoss at my current office so haven't got any experience with the maven tomcat integration.

see http://tomcat.apache.org/maven-plugin-2.0-SNAPSHOT/ and http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/ for some more details on both of these plugins.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the cargo [plugin](http://tshikatshikaaa.blogspot.nl/2012/07/how-to-deploy-war-to-tomcat-7-during.html) too. It works pretty well for me.