# Autodeploy to remote tomcat from IntelliJ

Tags: tomcat, jakarta-ee, intellij-idea, deployment, remote-server

I have to work with Tomcat & JavaEE at the moment. To deploy my webapplication I do it manually over the web-management gui.

[image]

*(marked red)*

As my IDE I use IntelliJ IDEA.

[image]

My Problem is that I do not find any description how to autodeploy my application to this tomcat (remote) server. All I found concerns using a local tomcat with remote one. This is shown below

[image]

*(In **Configure...** it is only possible to select a local tomcat (?!))*

[image]

Here is a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10349678/deploy-maven-war-file-to-tomcat-from-intellij) where one should use maven & cargo plugin.

Is this the only way to go or is it somehow possible to deploy to a remote tomcat without any installation of tomcat on my machine?

Comment: You ever get an answer outside of this question?

Comment: unfortunately no...

Comment: Still no answer?